# Nested attributes for checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model 'profile' that belongs to and has many 'services'.

On the profile page the user can tick which 'services' he has via check boxes.

At the moment I am struggling to get more than one of the checkbox values to add to the 'services' For example, in my view I have two checkboxes, if I check both boxes only the last checkbox checked gets added?

My view:

```
<h3>Please click the services you provide</h3>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="profile[services_attributes]
[services][service_type]" value="handyman">Handyman</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="profile[services_attributes]
[services][service_type]" value="plumber">Plumber</label>
      </div>
```

My controller:

```
def create
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

if @profile.save 

  redirect_to '/profiles' 

else
  render '/profiles'
    end
  end

  ...

  private

  def profile_params
params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, london_attributes: [:id, :south, 
:north, :east, :west, :central], services_attributes:[services: 
[:service_type]])
  end
end
```

Console error:

```
Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"rCk4/TbBsARCN2b9aSyxsXdW1mHBiZ1GrZNsmqTjsVIsDiQ294zYMlq0JkklRFeildiOLmfM3aYA0B3Lw+Apew==", 
"profile"=>{"bio"=>"", "services_attributes"=>{"services"=>{"service_type"=>"plumber"}}}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("bio", "created_at", "updated_at") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["bio", ""], ["created_at", "2016-02-20 
15:41:22.636669"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-20 15:41:22.636669"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "services" ("service_type", "created_at", 
"updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["service_type", "plumber"], ["created_at", 
"2016-02-20 15:41:22.638707"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-20 15:41:22.638707"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles_services" ("profile_id", "service_id") 
VALUES (?, ?)  [["profile_id", 124], ["service_id", 14]]
```

Comment: which was posted is not an error? Pls update

Comment: Hi Hieu, have updated my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refactor your view to:

```
<label>Handyman</label>
<%= check_box_tag 'profile[services_attributes]
[services][service_type][]', 'handyman' %>

<label>Plumber</label>
<%= check_box_tag 'profile[services_attributes]
[services][service_type][]', 'plumber' %>
```

Note that the checkbox name now is `profile[services_attributes][services][service_type][]`

Comment: Super that got me on my way!